# Setting proxy to urllib.request (Python3)

Tags: python, proxy, urllib

How can I set proxy for the last `urllib` in Python 3.
I am doing the next

```
from urllib import request as urlrequest
ask = urlrequest.Request(url)     # note that here Request has R not r as prev versions
open = urlrequest.urlopen(req)
open.read()
```

I  tried  adding  proxy as follows :

```
ask=urlrequest.Request.set_proxy(ask,proxies,'http')
```

However I don't know how correct it is since I am getting the next error:

```
336     def set_proxy(self, host, type):
--> 337         if self.type == 'https' and not self._tunnel_host:
    338             self._tunnel_host = self.host
    339         else:

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'type'
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should be calling `set_proxy()` on an *instance* of class `Request`, not on the class itself:

```
from urllib import request as urlrequest

proxy_host = 'localhost:1234'    # host and port of your proxy
url = 'http://www.httpbin.org/ip'

req = urlrequest.Request(url)
req.set_proxy(proxy_host, 'http')

response = urlrequest.urlopen(req)
print(response.read().decode('utf8'))
```

Comment: Pretty helpfull your  solution  hoewer  I am not able to put it in practice  due to  some tunneling issue .I must  mention that  I just   passed  a public proxy from  HMA , really helpfull If some could  help   in solving this issue .

Comment: @gm1: re your second comment: you need to use the correct HTTP scheme. If you set a HTTPS proxy it will only be used if you access HTTPS URLs. In your example the proxy is not used because the URL is HTTP, not HTTPS. Change the URL to `https://www.httpbin.org/ip` and it will use the proxy (which should be `https://195.154.231.43:3128`).

Comment: @gm1: That's good. If this answer was useful you can upvote it. If it is correct, you can accept it. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Hi , I would love to  hoewer I am not   able cause  I  dont  have enough reputation points

Comment: Hi , sureno  problem  but  how can I do that, I dont  find  any functionality for that is there a button or something?Tnks

Comment: I accepted , silly me  was   just the   so  obvious .Meanwhile something  wird  happened .It basically worked   until now when I get:`URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:645)>`

Answer (score 14):

I needed to **disable the proxy** in our company environment, because I wanted to access a server on localhost. I could not disable the proxy server with the approach from @mhawke (tried to pass `{}`, `None` and `[]` as proxies).

This worked for me (can also be used for setting a specific proxy, see comment in code).

```
import urllib.request as request

# disable proxy by passing an empty
proxy_handler = request.ProxyHandler({})
# alertnatively you could set a proxy for http with
# proxy_handler = request.ProxyHandler({'http': 'http://www.example.com:3128/'})

opener = request.build_opener(proxy_handler)

url = 'http://www.example.org'

# open the website with the opener
req = opener.open(url)
data = req.read().decode('utf8')
print(data)
```

Comment: does this download the file to disk?

Comment: @TheoF it decodes the response with utf-8 and stores it in the `data` variable. After that the output is printed. If does not store it into a file on your disk. If you want to store the response to a disk depending on the response you might not decode it and save it afterwords (see eg https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_write.asp)

Answer (score 5):

[Urllib will automatically detect proxies](https://docs.python.org/3.5/howto/urllib2.html#proxies) set up in the environment - so one can just set the `HTTP_PROXY` variable either in your environment e.g. for Bash:

```
export HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy_url:proxy_port
```

or using Python e.g.

```
import os
os.environ['HTTP_PROXY'] = 'http://proxy_url:proxy_port'
```

Note from the urllib docs: "`HTTP_PROXY`[environment variable] will be ignored if a variable `REQUEST_METHOD` is set; see the documentation on [getproxies](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.getproxies)()"

Comment: this is not the correct answer as it will set the proxy globally which can effect other processes outside python and more specifically it will break functionality that relies on localhost/loopback (like the AWS EC2 metadata IP address). The question is specifically about `urllib.request` and not the entire O/S

Comment: This works as an approach. The choice is up to the user - the `HTTP_PROXY` environment variable can be set per application, process, or globally.

Comment: In my experience os.environ has correct proxy settings however urllib is not picking it up. I have to explicitly set it up using urllib.request.ProxyHandler in order for it to work.

Comment: In the `urllib` docs I linked to in the answer they explicitly state it **does use the environment variables**. I've added to the answer a note from the docs about certain caveats.

Comment: Important note: It blows my mind that this is still the case in 2023 but, as per their [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/urllib2.html#proxies), _"Currently urllib.request does not support fetching of **https** locations through a proxy"_.

Answer (score 1):

```
import urllib.request
def set_http_proxy(proxy):
    if proxy == None: # Use system default setting
        proxy_support = urllib.request.ProxyHandler()
    elif proxy == '': # Don't use any proxy
        proxy_support = urllib.request.ProxyHandler({})
    else: # Use proxy
        proxy_support = urllib.request.ProxyHandler({'http': '%s' % proxy, 'https': '%s' % proxy})
    opener = urllib.request.build_opener(proxy_support)
    urllib.request.install_opener(opener)

proxy = 'user:pass@ip:port'
set_http_proxy(proxy)

url  = 'https://www.httpbin.org/ip'
request = urllib.request.Request(url)
response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
html = response.read()
html
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to setting global proxy for any request on your python code by setting it like below code :

```
import os
proxy = 'http://<user>:<pass>@<proxy>:<port>'
os.environ['http_proxy'] = proxy 
os.environ['HTTP_PROXY'] = proxy
os.environ['https_proxy'] = proxy
os.environ['HTTPS_PROXY'] = proxy
```

Comment: I use Ubuntu for Windows. This approach works, and urllib.request.ProxyHandler - not.