# Unable to use https proxy within urllib.request

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, proxy

I've created a script in python using `urllib.request` applying `https` proxy within it. I've tried like the following but it encounters different types of issues, as in `urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed----`. The script is supposed to grab the ip address from that site. The ip address used in the script is a placeholder. I've complied with the suggestion made [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34577116/9189799).

First attempt:

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://whatismyipaddress.com/proxy-check'

headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.88 Safari/537.36'}
proxy_host = '60.191.11.246:3128'

req = urllib.request.Request(url,headers=headers)
req.set_proxy(proxy_host, 'https')
resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp,"html5lib")
ip_addr = soup.select_one("td:contains('IP')").find_next('td').text
print(ip_addr)
```

Another way (using `os.environ`):

```
headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.88 Safari/537.36'}
proxy = '60.191.11.246:3128'

os.environ["https_proxy"] = f'http://{proxy}'
req = urllib.request.Request(url,headers=headers)
resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp,"html5lib")
ip_addr = soup.select_one("td:contains('IP')").find_next('td').text
print(ip_addr)
```

One more approach that I've tried with:

```
agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.88 Safari/537.36'
proxy_host = '205.158.57.2:53281'
proxy = {'https': f'http://{proxy_host}'}

proxy_support = urllib.request.ProxyHandler(proxy)
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(proxy_support)
urllib.request.install_opener(opener)
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', agent)]
res = opener.open(url).read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(res,"html5lib")
ip_addr = soup.select_one("td:contains('IP')").find_next('td').text
print(ip_addr)
```

How can I use https proxy within urllib.request in the right way?

Comment: Are you forced to use `urllib`?

Comment: Yes @AMC. I usually use proxies within requests. However, I got stuck when it comes to implement the same within urllib.request.

Comment: Is that the full error message? Where does the error occur? It would probably be difficult to provide a reproducible example for this, eh?

Comment: I can't find the relevant docs, but I think you have to use 'http' instead of 'https' as the protocol in `.set_proxy()` (eg: `req.set_proxy(proxy_host, 'http')`). With 'http' I have about the same success as with the `requests` lib, but when I use 'https' I'm only getting HTTP and Connection errors.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @t.m.adam. I got what you meant. However, you perhaps forgot to mention whether I use `http proxy` or `https proxy` within `proxy_host` variable. Btw, how I used proxy, as in `req.set_proxy(proxy_host, 'http')` is what I could see in the linked post. I'm always ready to comply with any better way as long as it is within `urllib.request`.

Comment: Does the problem persist if you change the protocol? This is how I tested: I took a bunch of free proxies and I tested each one, first with `requests` and then with your `urllib` code. It seems the response is more or less the same with both libraries, if the protocol is set to 'http' - I mean the second parameter in `.set_proxy()`, I didn't modify the format of the `proxy_host` string at all, and I think it's format should be `host:port`, without any protocol.

Comment: Hi @t.m.adam, what I meant is few proxies support `http` protocol whereas few support both `http` and `https`. So, which type of proxies should I supply within `proxy_host` variable?

Comment: `build_opener` approach is working with `{'https': 'https://51.91.137.248:3128'}` proxy

Comment: To be clearer - [this](https://filebin.net/b9sjh9z75cr9sr4w) is what I meant @t.m.adam.

Comment: It really is not working in my case @Sers. Did you change something before execution to make it work other than the proxy?

Comment: So, I ran some tests with free SSL proxies from this list: https://www.sslproxies.org/. I couldn't make it work with the `.set_proxy()` method, but Sers's suggestion seems to work. Here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36881923/7811673 you can find an example of `build_opener` with a `ProxyHandler`.

Comment: @MITHU no I did not. Problem is in the proxy you're using. Set manually (118.70.144.77:3128) proxy in browser and you'll see security issue in whatismyipaddress.com/proxy-check and google. This is a reason of response error you can get for some sites. But you it works, tried with `url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/'`

Comment: Yep, I came across that answer as well. I appended the rest of the portion to add the headers @t.m.adam. Am I right with the way I defined headers in there? Thanks.

Comment: This very site `https://stackoverflow.com/` works weirdly when there is any proxy involved @Sers. I'm using rotation of proxies where there are around 100 proxies, so I should not encounter that security issue.

Comment: Yes, you can add headers in the opener. BTW you can test your headers and other parts of the request with https://httpbin.org/anything

Comment: @MITHU it's depends on sites you'll go. Do you want to check if proxy is working before use it?

Comment: Finally it appears to be working @t.m.adam. Thanks Sers. Btw, is `build_opener()` the only way along with `{'https': 'https://51.91.137.248:3128'}`?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I couldn't make `.set_proxy()` work with SSL proxies.

Comment: As I mentioned before, `118.70.144.77` or `51.91.137.248` had security issue 
with `https://whatismyipaddress.com/proxy-check`, but now does not have. The problem was to many requests from same IP to google servers, and `https://whatismyipaddress.com/proxy-check` uses google's captcha. This was the reason error in `whatismyipaddress`, but it does not affect other sites. You can choose @t.m.adam or mine as accepted answer if you think the issue is solved.

Comment: @Sers It was your idea to use an opener, I just ran some tests. If one of us should take the credit it is you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While we were testing the proxes, there was [unusual traffic from your computer network](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/86640?hl=en) for Google services and that was the reason of response error, because [whatismyipaddress](https://whatismyipaddress.com/proxy-check) uses Google's services. But the issue was not affect other sites like stackoverflow.

```
from urllib import request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://whatismyipaddress.com/proxy-check'

proxies = {
    # 'https': 'https://167.172.229.86:8080',
    # 'https': 'https://51.91.137.248:3128',
    'https': 'https://118.70.144.77:3128',
}

user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.88 Safari/537.36'
headers = {
    'User-Agent': user_agent,
    'accept-language': 'ru,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,tr;q=0.7'
}

proxy_support = request.ProxyHandler(proxies)
opener = request.build_opener(proxy_support)
# opener.addheaders = [('User-Agent', user_agent)]
request.install_opener(opener)

req = request.Request(url, headers=headers)
try:
    response = request.urlopen(req).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response, "html5lib")
    ip_addr = soup.select_one("td:contains('IP')").find_next('td').text
    print(ip_addr)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Sers. Let us wait while the bounty is on, if anything new comes along.